# Bidirectional Iterators Next

Tags: c++, iterator, set

```
for(set<int> it = my_set.begin; it!= my_set.end; ++it)
for(set<int> other = next(it); other != my_set.end; ++other)
```

This won't compile because of std::next any suggestions on how I could implement a loop like this?  I tried using advance too but it also wouldn't work. (Note i know there are some syntax errors in the loop). Please no Boost library functions.

Comment: Can you please be more clear on what you're trying to achieve other than get it to compile?

Answer (score 1):

In C++03 you can use advance this way:

```cpp
for(std::set<int>::iterator it = my_set.begin(); it != my_set.end(); ++it) {
    std::set<int>::iterator copy = it;
    std::advance(copy, 1);
    for(; copy != my_set.end(); ++copy) {
        std::cout << *copy << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In C++11 you can use next instead:

```cpp
for(auto it = my_set.begin(); it != my_set.end(); ++it) {
    for(auto other = std::next(it); other != my_set.end(); ++other) {
        std::cout << *other << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first example `++copy` would seem simpler.

Comment: doesn't work next won't compile…. I ended up just using reverse iterators on the second loop and stopping when *other == *it

Comment: @GoBlue Like I said, it requires c++11, so can you explain what you mean by 'won't compile'?